# Efficiently using C structures with internal arrays of different sizes?

Tags: c, arrays, static, struct, size

I have embedded C code with a structure and associated "machinery" for implementing a ping-pong buffering scheme between and interrupt (filling the buffers) and user code (emptying the buffers). The struct consists of two buffers and a bit of management data, like so:

```
#define PINGPONG_BUF_SIZE 1024

 typedef struct
 {
     volatile unsigned char active_buf; // 0: buf0, 1: buf1
     volatile unsigned int idx;
    // [...misc. other management data snipped...]

    union
     {
         volatile uint16_t asInt[PINGPONG_BUF_SIZE/2];
         volatile char asChar[PINGPONG_BUF_SIZE];
     }buf0;

     union
     {
         volatile uint16_t asInt[PINGPONG_BUF_SIZE/2];
         volatile char asChar[PINGPONG_BUF_SIZE];
     }buf1;
 } pingpong;
```

The "machinery" consists of functions which take a pointer to a 'pingpong', e.g. pp_write_sample(pingpong * buf, uint16_t data).

Easy peasy so far. Now I would like to recycle that "machinery" to work on multiple such pingpong structs having different static buffer sizes (set at compile time). The buffer size can be stored as part of the management data, and the size of the management portion of the struct will always be the same. What is the cleanest way to do this?

It is for a very memory-limited embedded system, so creating buffers of the largest size and 'not using all of it' is not a solution. Also would be great to avoid dynamic allocation if at all possible (if it is even available for this platform).

Note, I am NOT interested in dynamically allocating or resizing anything at runtime, only being able to define 'pingpongs' of different sizes at compile-time with the least amount of copy+paste code or other ugliness. Some approaches I can think of are to make buf0/buf1 pointers to buffers which have been separately allocated (a bit ugly), or to create separate e.g. 'pingpong2048', 'pingpong_tiny', ... structs and cast them to 'pingpong' every time they are used (also ugly), but I'm wondering if there is a better way I don't know abut.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm presuming this is straight C and that type safe rules are fairly lax, no class overhead, etc...

so... you can declare your different structures and give them a common header...

```
struct ManagementHeader 
{ 
    ... 
};
```

then declare your different message types...

```
struct MessageType1
{ 
    ManagementHeader header; 
    SomeData body;
}

struct MessageType2
{
    ManagementHeader header;
    SomeOtherData body;
}

union PingPongMessage
{
    ManagementHeader header;
    MessageType1     type1;
    MessageType2     type2;
}
```

Now you can allocate message type 1 or message type 2 and pass it into the ping-pong as a pointer to a PingPongMessage, check the PingPongMessage's header to figure out what the message type is and use the type1 or type2 disambiguation attributes to access the fields. Therefore, you're not dynamically allocating changing block sizes, you're not allocating a PingPongMessage and wasting a ton of space, but you can use PingPongMessage to act as an interface for the process.